# Jupyter Note Book _ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'.Even after installation

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, cufflinks

I installed 'cufflinks on my pc as per the instructions provided on the anaconda website. I restarted the PC after installation. It is showing properly in the Anaconda environment also. Please see the below figure. But when running the code in the Jupyter notebook it says the cufflinks module is not there.
May I know what happened?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/90 this should help

Comment: I did all the things mentioned in the link you provided, but it did not help